# How to click a link with selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, hyperlink

How to click a link with selenium Webdriver which have same names

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("View All")).click();
```

There are some other Links also having same name like `View All`

Comment: can you please post the sample HTML code?

Comment: You mentioned that you have multiple "View All" links ryt? are they present inside any table with different user names?

Comment: does the two widgets have different class names or any different properties? Please post the HTML code for both the widgets.This will help us to provide you some reliable solutions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121798/discussion-between-sudharsan-selvaraj-and-boopathi).

Answer (score 2):

You should try to locate unique link with combinations of other attribute of this link such as class name and text by using `xpath` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement link = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//a[contains(@class, 'absence-viewall') and contains(text(), 'View All')]")));
link.click();
```

Or if this link has unique class name, best way to use `By.cssSelector()` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement link = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a.absence-viewall")));
link.click();
```